# JQuery animate() on width by setting element content

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Is there a way to animate the change in width upon setting a text() of an element?

Say, we have

`<a id="link" href="#">container/sub1/sub2</a>`

that is then changed programmatically by, say, `$('#link').text('sub2');` into this:

`<a id="link" href="#">sub2</a>`

Normally, said element's width will change instantly, but the effect I'm looking for is its gradual animated reduction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/HYZbA/

I have basically wrapped the `<a>` in a div with `overflow:hidden`. Then when the text is changed, the wrapper is animated to the size of the `a`.

NOTE:  The red border is just so you can see what's happening.  Remove this to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if to you can actually have the text animate into another text however I've done something to this effect by first using `fadeOut()` then setting the text and then using `fadeIn()` to have the text appear again. This will give an appearance of gradual change in text.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for my own solution, and based on James Montagne's answer, I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/HYZbA/33/ combining `fadeIn` / `fadeOut` as suggested by Albinoswordfish.